# Connection Pool running out of connection. Using DBCP2 BasicDataSource in Jetty embedded server

Tags: java, database, oracle, jetty, connection-pooling

Below are the details for configuring connection pool in my application. I am using Oracle 12C.

```
 initialSize=20    
 maxTotal=100
 minIdle=20
 maxWaitMillis=45000
 minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=3600000
 validationQueryTimeout=2
 removeAbandonedTimeout=10
 removeAbandonedTimeout=60
 removeAbandonedOnBorrow=true
 accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true
 testOnBorrow=true
 testWhileIdle=true
 logAbandoned=true
 defaultQueryTimeout=120
```

The number of active connections is progressive in nature and when it reached 100, it throws an error. For release connection I am using DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, datasource). I am also using DelegatingConnection in some places. In which cases the connections are not returned to the pool. I have run sonarqube but it doesnot show any potential connection leakages. Please suggest me if I need to change anything while configuring connection pool

Comment: Two entries for `removeAbandonedTimeout`?

Comment: That was a typo. One of them is for prod environment.

Comment: How fast is the pool exhausted? Are there slow queries? Get a heap dump and analyze it.

Comment: We have query time out set to 120 seconds. So even if any query take more than 120 seconds then it will throw exception and release the connection (written in finally). In my case, the number of active connections are increasing by 1 connection in 2 hrs approx and in 3 days pool is running out of connections.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the solution. The point to be noted is we should never close delegating connection, instead we should close the wrapper connection. It has fixed the problem which I was facing.